# How can I use the display() function in Microsoft Azure Notebook

Tags: python, azure

I am unable to display the .png file created by pyplot. I created the file in Microsoft Azure Jupyter Notebook. os.listdir() returns xx.png, so I know that the file was created. Yet, display(Image("xx.png")) does not show the image. I have read about ten related posts on stackoverflow and tried numerous variations of the command, but nothing works.

When I reproduce the problem on my local computer it works fine.

This question is a re-write of a previous question that was marked as duplicate and left to die. I hope that this post will make the question easier to understand.

Following is the code used to create the file:

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
y = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = numbers')
plt.title('Legend inside')
ax.legend()
fig.savefig('xx.png')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways given the code you have to show the image.

1) You can call `%matplotlib inline` at the top of the notebook. This will inline graphics and you will see the image by calling `fig`

2) You can `from IPython.display import Image` and `Image('xx.png')` and the image should be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are missing an `import` statement, try :

```
from Ipython.display import Image
display(Image("xx.png"))
```